# Testcafe error : An error occurred in Selector code: TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

[Dom Structure of HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umRIV.png)I am trying to automate a webpage using testcafe and wants to right click on the text present in the page

Please find attach image of my dom structure

This is the code I am trying to get tspan element (Highlighted in the dom structure)

```
export default class Login {
test = Selector('.process-view-div').child('process-view').shadowRoot()
demas = this.test.find('.yfiles-canvascomponent').child('.yfiles-svgpanel').child('div')
sad = this.demas.child(0)



async auth(user: string, password: string) : Promise<void> {
    await t
        .rightClick(this.sad)
} 
}
```

Till the demas variable, I am able to get the element value but when I am trying to go inside the demas child (i.e svg element) , it gives me the following error

"An error occurred in Selector code:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'."

Dom Structure (Attached in Image )[Dom Structure of HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqYMP.png)

Comment: I didn't manage to reproduce your example. Please share a simple sample that can be reproduced locally. If you don't want to share it here, you can create an issue in the TestCafe repository based on this template: [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml).